# How to sort an ArrayList with 2 int parameters?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort the arraylist of Process objects. A Process has 2 parameters: startTime and duration. I want to sort the arraylist in ascending order in startTime and for the same startTime, I want to sort in ascending order in duration. How should I do that?

Comment: You can start with trying :)

Comment: use [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) with a custom Comparator

Comment: Yo bro, check out [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). They're the ****.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming your Process class looks like this (plus other stuff):

```
public class Process{
   private int startTime;
   private int duration;

   public int getStartTime(){
       return startTime;
   }

   public int getDuration(){
       return duration;
   }
}
```

The first choice, the "default" sorting method for Processes is by the method you stated (first by startTime ascending, then by duration ascending), you could make Process implement `Comparable<Process>`:

```
public class Process implements Comparable<Process>{
   private int startTime;
   private int duration;

   public int compareTo(Process other){
       if(startTime < other.startTime) return -1;
       if(startTime > other.startTime) return 1;
       //If here, startTime == other.startTime
       if(duration < other.duration) return -1;
       if(duration > other.duration) return 1;
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can sort an `ArrayList<Process>` using the simple method:

```
ArrayList<Process> a = new ArrayList<Process>();

//Fill up a with process instances

Collections.sort(a); //Sorts according to the compareTo method in Process.
```

If, however, this isn't going to be the default method of sorting Processes, (or you aren't able to make Process implement Comparable, then you're going to want to define a custom `Comparator<Process>` as follows:

```
class ProcessComparator implements Comparator<Process>{
    public int compare(Process p1, Process p2){
       if(p1.getStartTime() < p2.getStartTime()) return -1;
       if(p1.getStartTime() > p2.getStartTime()) return 1;
       //If here, p1.startTime == other.startTime
       if(p1.getDuration() < p2.getDuration()) return -1;
       if(p1.getDuration() > p2.getDuration()) return 1;
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Then, use one as such:

```
ArrayList<Process> a = new ArrayList<Process>();

//Fill up a with process instances

Collections.sort(a, new ProcessComparator()); //Sorts according to the compareTo method in Process.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to create a custom `Comparator`.

Or you could create reusable Comparators to help with future sorts. For example you can use the [Bean Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) which allows you to sort on a property of your `Process` object. The link contains example code for using the `BeanComparator` or for creating your own custom `Comparator`.

You can then use the [Group Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/), which allows you to sort on multiple properties at the same time.